# How to Generate XSL code automatically?

Tags: xslt

I have UI which provide the facility to create own format by using drag and drop utility. I have also xml file which contains the data. Now task is how to automatically generate the .xsl file of the dynamically designed format for the data stored in xml form.

If you have any idea about the solution of the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once (in 2006) I was using [Altova MapForce](http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html) to create xslt transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...

Yes Altova and Stylus Studio are there to do the same work, But
Can you suggest me is there any opensource tool available to do the same or any idea how to Generate XSL. So that i can integrate this tech./tool to my project.

Thanks